# Evaluate nans slices size

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I have a spark dataframe with some `null` values in a column. I need to count the contiguous `null` values preceding a non null value.

Using `numpy` I'd do something like this (the code is not optimized for numpy because I'm trying not to use it in my problem):

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, None], [1, 3.], [2, 7.], [3, None], [4, 4.], [5, 3.], 
              [6, None], [7, None], [8, 5.], [9, 2.], [10, None]])

def nan_count(l, n):
    assert n <= len(l) + 1
    assert n >= 0

    if n < 1 or l[n-1] is not None:
        return 0
    return nan_count(l, n-1) + 1

y = map(lambda i: nan_count(x[:,1], i), x[:,0])
res = np.concatenate([x, np.asarray(y).reshape(-1,1)], axis = 1)
res
```

So that the output looks like this:

```py
Out[31]: [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0]
```

Now, if I have a spark DataFrame like `x`:

```
x = sc.parallelize([[0, None], [1, 3.], [2, 7.], [3, None], [4, 4.],
                    [5, 3.], [6, None], [7, None], [8, 5.], [9, 2.], [10, None]])\
      .toDF()
x.show()
```

```
+---+----+
| _1|  _2|
+---+----+
|  0|null|
|  1| 3.0|
|  2| 7.0|
|  3|null|
|  4| 4.0|
|  5| 3.0|
|  6|null|
|  7|null|
|  8| 5.0|
|  9| 2.0|
| 10|null|
+---+----+
```

How do I obtain the same output?

I've altready tried some workarouds using `udf`, but I have problems in referencing the value before the one selected (I tried using `select` and `filter` `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` methods inside the udf, but it is not allowed).

**EDIT**: I do not know how many consecutive `nans` I might find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I putted comments into code to explain each step until reach the desired output.

Of course it's unnecessary create all columns from example below and probably this code can be a lot improved, but I think it's important show you step by step and do a initial kick off to solve your question.

```py
x = sc.parallelize([
    [0, None],
    [1, 3.],
    [2, 7.],
    [3, None],
    [4, 4.],
    [5, 3.],
    [6, None],
    [7, None],
    [8, 5.],
    [9, 2.],
    [10, None]
])
# Assigned values ​​in columns A and B to facilitate manipulation
x = x.toDF(['A', 'B'])

# Prints initial DF
x.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+
|  A|   B|
+---+----+
|  0|null|
|  1| 3.0|
|  2| 7.0|
|  3|null|
|  4| 4.0|
|  5| 3.0|
|  6|null|
|  7|null|
|  8| 5.0|
|  9| 2.0|
| 10|null|
+---+----+
```

```py
# Transform null values into "1"
x = x.withColumn('C', when(x.B.isNull(), 1))
x.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+----+
|  A|   B|   C|
+---+----+----+
|  0|null|   1|
|  1| 3.0|null|
|  2| 7.0|null|
|  3|null|   1|
|  4| 4.0|null|
|  5| 3.0|null|
|  6|null|   1|
|  7|null|   1|
|  8| 5.0|null|
|  9| 2.0|null|
| 10|null|   1|
+---+----+----+
```

```py
# Creates a spec that order column A
order_spec = Window().orderBy('A')

# Doing a cumulative sum. See the explanation
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384625/pyspark-cumulative-sum-with-reset-condition
x = x \
    .withColumn('tmp', sum((x.C.isNull()).cast('int')).over(order_spec)) \
    .withColumn('D', sum(x.C).over(order_spec.partitionBy("tmp"))) \
    .drop('tmp')
x.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+----+----+
|  A|   B|   C|   D|
+---+----+----+----+
|  0|null|   1|   1|
|  1| 3.0|null|null|
|  2| 7.0|null|null|
|  3|null|   1|   1|
|  4| 4.0|null|null|
|  5| 3.0|null|null|
|  6|null|   1|   1|
|  7|null|   1|   2|
|  8|null|   1|   3|
|  9| 5.0|null|null|
| 10| 2.0|null|null|
| 11|null|   1|   1|
+---+----+----+----+
```

```py
# Put values from column D to one row above and select the desired output values
x = x.withColumn('E', lag(x.D, ).over(order_spec)) \
    .select(x.A, x.B, when(col('E').isNotNull(), col('E')).otherwise(0).alias('nan_count'))
x.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+---------+
|  A|   B|nan_count|
+---+----+---------+
|  0|null|        0|
|  1| 3.0|        1|
|  2| 7.0|        0|
|  3|null|        0|
|  4| 4.0|        1|
|  5| 3.0|        0|
|  6|null|        0|
|  7|null|        1|
|  8|null|        2|
|  9| 5.0|        3|
| 10| 2.0|        0|
| 11|null|        0|
+---+----+---------+
```

Entire code:

```py
from pyspark.shell import sc
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import lag, when, sum, col

x = sc.parallelize([
    [0, None], [1, 3.], [2, 7.], [3, None], [4, 4.],
    [5, 3.], [6, None], [7, None], [8, None], [9, 5.], [10, 2.], [11, None]])
x = x.toDF(['A', 'B'])

# Transform null values into "1"
x = x.withColumn('C', when(x.B.isNull(), 1))

# Creates a spec that order column A
order_spec = Window().orderBy('A')

# Doing a cumulative sum with reset condition. See the explanation
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384625/pyspark-cumulative-sum-with-reset-condition
x = x \
    .withColumn('tmp', sum((x.C.isNull()).cast('int')).over(order_spec)) \
    .withColumn('D', sum(x.C).over(order_spec.partitionBy("tmp"))) \
    .drop('tmp')

# Put values from column D to one row above and select the desired output values
x = x.withColumn('E', lag(x.D, ).over(order_spec)) \
    .select(x.A, x.B, when(col('E').isNotNull(), col('E')).otherwise(0).alias('nan_count'))
x.show()
```

Comment: It partially works: I forgot to say that I may have more than two consecutive `nans`: the code you sent is right until 2 consecutive `nans`, if there are more it just writes `2`. I think the problem is in the `sum_between` line of your code, am I right?

Comment: Yes, but that was a dummy dataset, I have a long time series from a sensor, and it happens that it misses some readings, and buffers the values. I may have empty values in sequences longer than two, i.e. `[…,1.5, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 6.7, ...]`